# How to show only a specific file format in ctrlp results?

Tags: filesystem, plugin-ctrlp

I am fairly new to Vim. I keep my notes in `.md` files and would like to access them with CtrlP from several different directories. I would like to set a specific filter on them, because now loading all the files and changing the search patter quickly slows down vim a lot.

I understand that there are `wildignore` and `ctrlp_custom_ignore` for **ignoring** specific files formats. However, based on [this issue](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim/issues/312), for **filtering** for particular patterns, I might need to use `ctrlp_user_command` instead.

Currently, I have the default setting:

```
let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'rg %s --files --hidden --color=never --glob ""'
```

I tried to adjust it based on the issue but the examples there use `find` instead of `rg` and I am confused with the vim regex (I am familiar with regex mainly in python and somehow in js).

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, and your goal is for CtrlP only to list files that have an `.md` extension, you just need to alter the `--glob` field in the rg command you included in your question:

```
let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'rg %s --files --hidden --color=never --glob "*.md"'
```

Comment: Yes, this did what I was aiming for. Thanks!